# How to logout Metamask from react js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js, metamask

i am implementing a dApp using react js and web3.js i have implemented the metamask login but i want to have a button logout which logout the metamask account from the application , i have tried to install wagmi and rainbowkit libraries to acheive the metamask logout , but i had a mismatch conflicts between typescript version my app uses and the version these libraries use and dependencies conflict .
So what is the solution to logout metamask using a button from my app and are there any other libraries to do that ? Thank you .